# Swift / Instagram API - how to auth with Instagram App

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I need an `AccessToken` to have the User have granted access to his own Instagram Account within my App. I've registered everything within the Instagram Development Center.

Currently I'm using [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth/wiki/Instagram) to receive an `AccessToken` by Instagram.

So far everything is working well. I'm receiving the Token and am able to use it.

**But** when I wanted to login for the first time, I've noticed, that I had no idea what my password was. I always log in with Facebook or am already logged in. I don't want to have my users face the same issues and have them reset their Instagram password...

I have googled for a while now, without success. **Is there a way to authenticate the User and receive an AccessToken using the Instagram App?**

I already have added instagram to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` at the `info.plist` and sending images to the Instagram App to post them there is working. So calling the app itself is not the issue.

This is my current code that opens a WebView within a UIViewController - but the User has to login with username and password.

[image]

**Update to the code for:** [how to auth with Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286744/oauth2-swift-3-instagram/40373964#40373964)

What are my possibilities? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought of using Instagram's API instead of a WebView?
 - https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: I don't really get your question. I AM using Instagram API. Like with client ID and redirect URI and stuff.

Comment: But in the documentation, I can only find code snipets to call for an access token using a URL connection as well.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase. Why are you using a WebView?

Like what are you trying to accomplish? Log in to a user's account? Post a photo? etc?

Comment: Because I can't find another opportunity. That is kinda like the point of my question :D

Comment: To have the user access his account I need to call an API URL using my client ID and redirect URI - clear so far. But so the user is able to accept it, I have to redirect him to a Instagram source and I only find solutions using web View, but I WANT the instagram app to open

Comment: Like my question sais, all i need is a access token. To have access to user's feed for example

Comment: so i need to "auth" the user and the user has to login or "accept" it. but that has to happen within an instagram environment

Comment: I'm sorry if anything wasn't perfectly clear. I've updated my question. Thank you for your feedback and effort

Comment: If U use Instagramengine then I will help you

Comment: How would you be able to help me then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot use Instagram app to authenticate Instagram account at the moment.

However, web view seems to be a reasonable way to login especially in iOS 9 and above because it does not require user to switch between apps and having to tap on dialogs to switch app. The only pain is for the user to type username and password, but hopefully they only need to do that once (unless they change account).

Facebook has similar issue and choose to go with web view login as default way to authenticate.

> For the people who are not signed into Facebook on Safari, they will only need to log into Facebook one time. After that, every future Facebook Login experience is fast and convenient with no extra steps. This means that as adoption of this flow increases over time, so does the quality of the experience people get. In contrast, the traditional fast-app-switch flow does not improve over time: The additional dialogs continue to appear in both directions for every new app that people log into.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/

Comment: thank you for your help. i have awarded the bounty to you