# OAuth2, Swift 3, Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, instagram, oauth-2.0

There seem to be lots of changes at IG. Many OAuth2 repos, all seem to have bugs, or really not easily converted to Swift3. Wondering if anyone has a solution for moving to Swift3 and working with the latest changes at Instagram?

Solutions most welcome. OAuth2 implementation seems to one of the more complicated things out there. Surprised that IG has not offered their own example docs on how to do this with iOS. They only have docs for web based solutions.

Maybe something brewing there? Zillions of coders they have on staff. But for now, on the hunt for a (dare I say?) simple solution.

thanks a million. :-)

Comment: I use OAuth2 in Swift 3 to log in facebook. I think it's similar...if you want...I could post for you.

Comment: Yes, FB is cool, but different than Instagram. Instagram is the tricky one I need to solve. The call back URL is the puzzle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For Swift 3:**

**Update: April 17 2017**: Because of broken dependencies, the installation by Pods is no longer working. Therefore I have ripped the needed content and created a **[new Github project](https://github.com/davidseek/SimpleAuthInstagram)** using a Bridging Header and stored all the needed files within the project. If you clone or download the github project, you'll instantly be able to login to Instagram.

To use those files in your project, simply drag and drop all the files from the SimpleAuth folder to your project, make sure to mark `copy item if needed`

[image]

Also you need to disable `Disable implicit oAuth` within the Instagram developer console.

[image]

Then you either copy/paste my code from the Bridging Header into your or you use mine. Set the Bridging Header at the Target's Build Settings.

[image]

Everything else works as before:

I have a struct for the Instagram Account:

```
struct InstagramUser {

    var token: String = ""
    var uid: String = ""
    var bio: String = ""
    var followed_by: String = ""
    var follows: String = ""
    var media: String = ""
    var username: String = ""
    var image: String = ""
}
```

The function to receive the token:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
var user: InstagramUser?
let INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID = "16ee14XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
let INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI = "http://www.davidseek.com/just_a_made_up_dummy_url" //just important, that it matches your developer account uri at Instagram

extension ViewController {

    func connectInstagram() {

        let auth: NSMutableDictionary = ["client_id": INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                                         SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI]

        SimpleAuth.configuration()["instagram"] = auth            
        SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", options: [:]) { (result: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in

            if let result = result as? JSONDictionary  {

                var token = ""
                var uid = ""
                var bio = "" 
                var followed_by = ""
                var follows = ""
                var media = ""
                var username = ""
                var image = ""

                token = (result["credentials"] as! JSONDictionary)["token"] as! String
                uid = result["uid"] as! String

                if let extra = result["extra"] as? JSONDictionary,
                    let rawInfo = extra ["raw_info"] as? JSONDictionary,
                    let data = rawInfo["data"] as? JSONDictionary {

                    bio = data["bio"] as! String

                    if let counts = data["counts"] as? JSONDictionary {
                        followed_by = String(describing: counts["followed_by"]!)
                        follows = String(describing: counts["follows"]!)
                        media = String(describing: counts["media"]!)
                    }
                }

                if let userInfo = result["user_info"] as? JSONDictionary {
                    username = userInfo["username"] as! String
                    image = userInfo["image"] as! String
                }

                self.user = InstagramUser(token: token, uid: uid, bio: bio, followed_by: followed_by, follows: follows, media: media, username: username, image: image)


            } else {
                // this handles if user aborts or the API has a problem like server issue
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            if error != nil {
                print("Error during SimpleAuth.authorize: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instagram also says:

> **Important**
>
> Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your
>   app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or
>   Instagram expires the token after some period of time. If the token is
>   no longer valid, API responses will contain an
>   “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException”. In this case you will need to
>   re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token. In other words:
>   do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

So handle the case of receiving the `OAuthAccessTokenException`

Comment: hi david,  thanks for the info. I'm really looking for a Swift3 version. 

SimpleAuth does not compile with the latest xcode.

Comment: dude. i'm using it with the latest xcode in a swift 3 project. if i would not, i would not have taken 30 minutes of my life to write that answer

Comment: all you need to to do is to compile the dependencies of simpleauth to swift 3... uploading a sample project in a second for you...

Comment: literally ALL you need to do is to change the `Result.swift` and the `ResultType.swift` files from the `Result` pod to the ones i'm providing you in a second AND delete `ALL THE SWIFT FILES` from the `reactive cocoa` pod. you will see in a second

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. Swift3+OAuth2+changes to IG API, and not allowing oauth:// in their redirect value seems to have complicated things.

Comment: this does exactly what i have told you to do in my answer. and as I said, with the SimpleAuth Framework, the compiler complains because of some of the dependencies. just change the `Result.swift` and `ResultType.swift` to the ones in my project (just copy paste the code!) and delete `ALL` the swift files from the `reactive cocoa` and you're done

Comment: I have added the explanation into my answer on top. You will see in the project, that you just need to enter your ID and URI, login within the app and then you will have everything perfectly printed to the console. it works 100%. I have just tried it for you.

Comment: hi david, thanks. marked this as the correct answer.

http://imgur.com/a/4Mw6j

Questions:
My goal is now I have a valid token from IG, allowing the user to DL's my app to do a query in the form of attached image.

2. Why no secret? Don't we need that key? How were you able to work around that?

3. Wow, you seem to be on top of Swift. Any tips (sites, blow, books) that you recommend to get up to speed in Swift.

thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127196/discussion-between-david-seek-and-edward-potter).

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @DavidSeek You deserve a 1000 upvote for this answer here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a file named ResultProtocol.swift Should i change that file with ResultType.swift?

Comment: @AnuragSharma I don't know right now. Where is this file from? What dependency? Just follow my tut or download the sample project.

Comment: Yes , after downloading sample project . I got 43 errors of file not found and all in pod

Answer (score 0):

This Code bellow I use for facebook and google+, I think it'ill work for Instagram too, maybe some adjusts.

```
import UIKit

class Signup: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    let GOOGLE_ID = "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    let GOOGLE_SECRET = "xxxxxxx";
    let GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI="http://yourdomain.com/api/account/googlecallback"
    let GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    let GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
    let GOOGLE_OAUTH_SCOPE = "profile email";
    let GOOGLE_GET_PROFILE = "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me";
    let FACEBOOK_ID = "xxxxx";
    let FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI = "http://yourdomain.com/api/account/facebookcallback";
    let FACEBOOK_OAUTH_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=";
    let FACEBOOK_OAUTH_SCOPE = "public_profile,email"
    let FACEBOOK_GET_PROFILE = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
    var currentURL: String = ""
    var queryString: String = ""
    var receivedToken: String = ""
    var authCode: String = ""
    var authComplete = false
    var webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    @IBAction func google(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        AppVars.Provider = "Google"
        webV.delegate = self
        let url = GOOGLE_OAUTH_URL + "?redirect_uri=" + GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI + "&response_type=code&client_id=" + GOOGLE_ID + "&scope=" + GOOGLE_OAUTH_SCOPE
        let urlString :String =  url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        webV.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!))
        self.view.addSubview(webV)
    }

    @IBAction func facebook(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        AppVars.Provider = "Facebook"
        webV.delegate = self
        let url = FACEBOOK_OAUTH_URL + FACEBOOK_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI + "&scope=" + FACEBOOK_OAUTH_SCOPE + "&display=popup&response_type=token"
        let urlString :String =  url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        webV.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!))
        self.view.addSubview(webV)
    }
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
         self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        currentURL = (webView.request?.url!.absoluteString)!
        if AppVars.Provider == "Google" {
           googleSignup((webView.request?.url!)!)
        } else {
           facebookSignup((webView.request?.url!)!)
        }
    }

    func googleSignup (_ returnCode: URL) {
            let url = String(currentURL)
            if (url?.range(of: "?code=") != nil && authComplete != true) {
                authCode =  getQueryItemValueForKey("code", url: returnCode)!
                authComplete = true
                let paramString = "code=" + authCode + "&client_id=" + GOOGLE_ID + "&client_secret=" +
                    GOOGLE_SECRET + "&redirect_uri=" + GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                self.requestServer(urlSource: GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL, params: paramString, requestType: "POST") { (dataResult, errorResult) -> () in
                    if errorResult != nil {
                         self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
                    } else {
                        let dataString:NSString = NSString(data: dataResult as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                        let dataResult2 = dataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)!
                        do {
                            let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResult2, options: .allowFragments)  as! [String:Any]
                            if let token = jsonDict["access_token"] as? String {
                                self.requestServerSignup(self.GOOGLE_GET_PROFILE, param: token, requestType: "GET") { (dataResult, errorResult) -> () in
                                    if errorResult != nil {
                                         self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
                                    } else {
                                        let dataString:NSString = NSString(data: dataResult as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                                        let dataResult2 = dataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)!
                                        do {
                                            let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResult2, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                                            if let name = jsonDict["name"] as? String {
                                                AppVars.NameLogin = name
                                                AppVars.PictureLogin = jsonDict["picture"] as! String
                                                AppVars.EmailLogin = jsonDict["email"] as! String
                                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "externalLoginSegue", sender: self)
                                                // show picture, email and name for checking profile
                                            }
                                        } catch  {
                                             self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } catch  {
                             self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.webV.removeFromSuperview()
            }

    }

    func facebookSignup(_ returnCode: URL) {
            let url = String(currentURL)
            if (url?.range(of: "access_token=") != nil && authComplete != true) {
                let url2: String = returnCode.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#access_token", with: "access_token")
                let url3: URL = URL(string: url2)!
                authCode =  getQueryItemValueForKey("access_token", url: (url3))!
                authComplete = true
                let paramString = "code=" + authCode + "&client_id=" + GOOGLE_ID + "&client_secret=" +
                    GOOGLE_SECRET + "&redirect_uri=" + GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                self.requestServer(urlSource: self.FACEBOOK_GET_PROFILE + authCode + "&fields=name,picture,email", params: paramString, requestType: "GET") { (dataResult, errorResult) -> () in
                    if errorResult != nil {
                         self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
                    } else {
                        let dataString:NSString = NSString(data: dataResult as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                        let dataResult2 = dataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)!
                        do {
                            let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResult2, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                            if let name = jsonDict["name"] as? String {
                                AppVars.NameLogin = name
                                if let picture = jsonDict["picture"] as? [String:Any] {
                                    if let dataPicture = picture["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                                        if let url = dataPicture["url"] as? String {
                                            AppVars.PictureLogin = url
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                AppVars.EmailLogin = jsonDict["email"] as! String
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "externalLoginSegue", sender: self)
                                // show picture, email and name for checking profile
                            }

                        } catch  {
                             self.showAlert(self, message: "Internet is not working")
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.webV.removeFromSuperview()
            }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func getQueryItemValueForKey(_ key: String, url: URL) -> String? {
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return nil }
        return queryItems.filter {
            $0.name == key
            }.first?.value
    }

   func requestServer(urlSource:String, params:String, requestType:String, result:@escaping (_ dataResult:NSData?, _ errorResult:NSError?) -> ()) {
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlSource)!
        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        request.httpMethod = requestType
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        if params.characters.count > 0 {
            request.httpBody = params.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    result(data as NSData?, nil)
                } else {
                    result(nil, error as NSError?)
                }
            })
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: hi clever,thanks for info. IG is a bit different then Google or FB. A funny return type, and token vs code returned values. Also need to have a Swift3 solution.