# Mobile app redirect URI for Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use Instagram login in my iOS app.
I want my users to be redirected to my app once they have logged in. The uri is : ig042ad046b655491b8f34d2a70f18f7bd://authorize
However, Instagram only seems to accept http(s) URIs and thus cannot redirect the user to my app.

[image]

[image]

How should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue for ages. Turns out the redirect uri doesn't really matter (at all!) - you can use a dummy one as long as it matches.

[OAuth2, Swift 3, Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286744/oauth2-swift-3-instagram/40373964#40373964)

Have a look at the above, hope it helps you. I spent days messing around with redirect uris, etc. til that worked for me.

Comment: I got that it had to match, the thing is that Instagram does not seem to accept custom URI. I want my URI to use deep linking to my app but Instagram does not accept this type of URL it seems. I contacted them but I still have no answer. For now my workaround is to redirect the user to a URL that will redirect it to my app. But that's annoying

Comment: Yeah you're trying to do something like com.appname.app:// in the Instagram security page, right? And it only accepts https://

Comment: Sorry seems like I can't edit my previous comment - just wanted to add that the SimpleAuth pod I linked above handles redirection back to the app automatically.