# redirect URI doesn't match registered redirect uri Instagram iOS

Tags: ios, ios10, instagram-api, xcode8

I am integrating Instagram login through this sdk https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk

I registered my app with Redirect URI "http://www.webvillee.com/callback" and got Client ID and Secret ID.

Now when I want to login through app it is showing **Error 400 "Redirect URI does not match registered Redirect URI"**.

I also tried to update my Redirect URI in **Security** session with **ig+Client ID+://authorize** but it is giving me error of invalid website. also I haved change URL Schemes in my app info.

Can any one lead me to register my app and also tell me the reason causes error in my code. Thank you

**Edit:**
this is my code to authenticate

```
self.instagram = [[Instagram alloc] initWithClientId:APP_ID
                                            delegate:nil];
```

Comment: show your code where you are trying to authenticate user.

Comment: Hi, @M Swapnil have you found solution? i'm also facing same problem, if yes, could you please tell me?

Comment: @FrankLindstrom I changed redirect url from **http://www.webvillee.com/callback** to **http://webvillee.com/**

Answer (score 1):

I went through **http://codegerms.com** example of Instagram login and changed my Redirect URI from "http://www.webvillee.com/callback" to "http://webvillee.com/". For now it is working fine I don't know if It is permanent solution or not, but it worked for me.

Hope this will help to some other developers.

**Edit**

Start from  [here](http://codegerms.com/?s=instagram%20login)

Comment: i already found solution from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286744/oauth2-swift-3-instagram. Btw I think your solution will work too, thank you for your answer.