# "Enter a valid website" when entering Redirect URI in instagram in ios

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

I'm currently developing iOS app and implemenet Instagram login.
When I entered `igeb6240d263fb4736b3740af87edd18ea://authorize` in Redirect URI in instagram developer center, I got this message `Enter a valid website"`

I think it works fine until October or so, but this is new problem.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing many hours of research I finally find solution from this link.
[OAuth2, Swift 3, Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286744/oauth2-swift-3-instagram)

We can integrate instagram with SimpleAuth library as mentioned there.

I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webpage which redirects the Instagram redirect url to the custom url scheme of your iOS app (including all the url parameters). The only disadvantage of this solution is that you need a server to host this webpage.

Comment: Can you give me some example please